# uninitialized memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I am ware that the std::vector.reserve() method reserves the capacity of a vector, and accessing to a vector which is reserved but not manually initialized with values will lead to an undefined behavior. But I was told that the reserve() method does actually fill something into the allocated memory, so it can't be an uninitialized memory allocation, right? So is there ever a way to allocate uninitialized memory in c++ (like how mcalloc() works for c)?

EDIT: sorry I put the wrong word here, it should be like how mcalloc() works for c. I've changed that.

Comment: `like how calloc() works for c`.. are you joking or serious? That's like 180 degrees opposite statement.

Comment: `calloc` allocates initialized memory. There is a way to allocate uninitialized memory in C++ like how `malloc` works for C: it's to use `malloc`. There is also a way to allocate memory in C++ like how `calloc` works for C: it's to use `calloc`

Comment: The answers are diverging a bit -- could you please clarify whether `std::vector` is the crux of your question or just an example ? Do you want to put an uninitialized object inside a vector, or simply allocate uninitialized memory yourself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The undefined behaviour comes from violating the contract of the `std::vector` interface.**

Yes, memory is allocated, so you will not get a memory access violation from that.

No, it is not initialised. It's likely created using `new char[N]` or somesuch, so it's just a bunch of uninitialised `char`s providing a "playground" on which the vector can build stuff later.

For an integral element type that's not a problem (unless you're going to be reading the indeterminate values). For class types, that's a problem, as their constructors have not been run and so the objects "do not exist".

Could you hack around it by manually creating objects at that location? Perhaps with placement new? Sure. In fact, that's what the vector does! But you'd still be violating the interface of `std::vector`, imbuing your program with Undefined Behaviour and so — from a black box perspective — you have to accept that anything might happen, no matter how well you think you hacked around it under the bonnet.

Instead, you can create such an object properly by just, y'know, adding to the vector using its documented interface. So just do that.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the new operator it does not initialize the memory if you are using an integer datatype.  Such as `char* my_mem = new char[N]`.  This memory will be uninitialized and can contain any value.  However if you had something like `std::string my_words = new std::string[N]`.  Theses would all be initialized to empty strings since it is a class and new calls the default constructor.  That being said I would imagine that the reserve function follows this behavior.  If it is reserving a class it would call the default constructor and if it is an integer type it would not.

Comment: I hope that `reserve`() in this context does not call any ctors. That would be costly when the ctors are costly. (It may require their presence at compile time, iiuc, though.)

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers:

> I am ware that the std::vector.reserve(n) method reserves the capacity
> of a vector

Yes, "reserves the capacity" here involves some kind of memory allocation (but you don't know exactly how much except that it is equal or larger than `n` elements.

> , and accessing to a vector which is reserved but not manually initialized with values will lead to an undefined behavior.

The undefined behavior comes in from using element indices larger than `vector::size()`.
It could be fine for trivial types, like `int`. or anything that can be used in an uninitialized state.

> But I was told that the reserve() method does actually fill something into the allocated memory, so it can't be an uninitialized memory allocation, right?

It *is* an uninitialized memory allocation, `reserve` doesn't fill anything because that would defeat the purpose of the `reserve` optimization. `reserve` can be expensive (allocation) but it has to be an `O(1)` operation (i.e. independent of the size or the capacity).

> So is there ever a way to allocate uninitialized memory in c++ (like how mcalloc() works for c)?

In some place you find the suggested to use `vector::reserve` on an empty vector to have an uninitialized buffer of trivial types.
It probably works but it is problematic anyway because you have to store the size of your buffer somewhere else and neither `vector::size` nor `vector::capacity` can play that role.
You cannot use `resize` either because that will "overwrite" your elements.
That is, that vector cannot be used as such anywhere else in your program.

> EDIT: sorry I put the wrong word here, it should be like how mcalloc() works for c. I've changed that.

In C++98, the correct way to get uninitialized memory this is to use `std::allocator<T>::allocate/deallocate`, IMO.

In C++11 you can use additionally `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` with automatic management.